# Axios GET - send object values instead of actual object

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm having a weird issue here.  I am using Axios and doing a GET request.  I need to send a bunch of values in the params object.  If I send just an object `dataObject`, I don't get back the correct response.  But if I manually type in the values from the object as key value pairs, I get back the correct response. So I want my sent params to look like this:

[image]

However, when I just send the object, it looks like this:
[image]

So I'm thinking there has to be some sort of operation I can do on the object to pull out the individual pairs, but I'm not figuring it out.

Here are the two different Axios versions:

```
return axios.get(GET_ENDPOINT, {
    params: {
      dataObject

return axios.get(GET_ENDPOINT, {
    params: {
      //dataObject
      20090519001:'',
      iid:1444430872256,
      accessoryIdString:'',
      mode:'addToCart',
      quantity:1,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be sending `params` as an object within the params object:

`params: { dataObject: { etc } }`

but axios expects a shallow object, so what you want is

`params: dataObject`

Comment: That was it!  I figured it was something ridiculously simple, and I was right!  Thank you!